# Lisp Scheme using (string-set!) Error Encountered

Tags: string, lisp, scheme

I am new to (Lisp) scheme programming and have been following the tutorial. Everything went well until I use string-set!

String-set! is use to replace the character at index. An example of what I did below:

```
Welcome to Racket v5.1.3.
> (define greeting "Hello; Hello!")
> (string-set! greeting 1 #\a)
string-set!: expects type <mutable string> as 1st argument, given: "Hello; Hello!"; other arguments were: 1 #\a

 === context ===
/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:85:7

> greeting
"Hello; Hello!"
>
```

When `(string-set! greeting 1 #\a)` executed, it should replace the first '**e**' to '**a**' according to the tutorial. The output should be:

```
> greeting
"Hallo; Hello!"
```

But instead I am getting the error `string-set!: expects type <mutable string> as 1st argument`.
Am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html):

> A string can be mutable or immutable. When an immutable string is provided to a procedure like `string-set!`, the `exn:fail:contract` exception is raised. String constants generated by the default reader (see Reading Strings) are immutable, and they are interned in `read-syntax` mode.

You can use `string-copy` to make a copy of a string, and this always returns a mutable string.

```
(define greeting (string-copy "Hello; Hello!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not suppose to work according to the [R5RS](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_520) or [R6RS](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs-lib-std/r6rs-lib-Z-H-19.html?q=set-cdr%21#node_idx_1280). It clearly states:

```
(define (g) "***")
(string-set! (g) 0 #\?)          ===>  error
```

It might be an error in your tutorial. You need to make the string mutable:

```
(define greeting (string-copy "Hello; Hello!"))
(string-set! greeting 1 #\a)
greeting ; ==>  "Hallo; Hello!"
```

BTW: When you start `Racket` from command line or `DrRacket` in a windowed environment your are not expected to write `Scheme`, but a dialect that has diverged from the standard called `racket`. Most of `Scheme` will work though, but not set-car! or set-cdr!.

I advice you to use a Scheme standard according your tutorial. To use racket to run a Scheme standard from command line, you start either `plt-r5rs` or `plt-r6rs`. In `DrRacket` you can use choose language in the bottom left. Choose "Other > Legacy language R5RS" or select The racket language and start your definitions windows with:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))
```

DrRacket has a debugger so I recommend it. I googled your line and if you are following *Teach Yourself Scheme in Fixnum Days*, it conforms to the [R5RS standard](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_start).

If you rather want to learn `racket` I recommend [Realm of racket (2013)](http://realmofracket.com/) since you make games, which are fun. There is also a free book called [How to design programs (2003)](http://htdp.org/).

Comment: Yes, but `(define (g) "***")` evaluates to a procedure. He is effectively writing `(define g "***")` which evaluates to a string, and works with `string-set!` just fine according to R5RS.

Comment: @JustinEthier You agree `(define x (g))` is the same as `(define x "***")`? If you do `(string-set! x 0 #\?)` in Ikarus, Chicken, or Gambit you will get "?**" from there on when you do (g). It is in violation of R5RS that it works and Racket has fixed that since that tutorial was written.

Comment: I see what you are saying now; the specs should be more clear on mutable/immutable strings. I tested on Chicken and chibi (granted, that is R7RS) and neither throws an error due to immutable strings. Racket must have a more strict implementation of R5RS.